# Need help identifying a web part in one of our sites

Tags: web-part, document-library, app-part

we had an external person come in to help us build a sharepoint site and i'm needing a bit of assistance identifying the name of a web/app part they used (pictured). It's a web/app part that references a document library on the site and organises it by tag/year. If you know what it's called i'd love some assistance here, i've been unable to find it :)[image]

Comment: Looks like it is view grouped by the year....can you click on modify view in the ribbon and check the group by condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `list view webpart` associated with a document library. In your document library there is a column named as Year (could be calculated or another type column) and the view pictured here is a group by of the documents based on the year column.

To find out which document library its associated with, click on one of the documents and you will find out the path of the document library. Or you can go to `View All Site Content` (clicking on top right gear icon on the page) , there you will find all the lists and document libraries present. By default in a SharePoint site, the document library is named as `Documents` or `Shared Documents`,or it be that you have created a your own library named something like `Annual Reports`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response here. I am wanting to add another list view webpart like this one - is it a default webpart that I can find in the insert column somewhere or not that simple?

Comment: Yes its available OOTB. Edit the page > click on add a webpart. In the webpart gallery section you will find the document library in the defaults apps sections.

Comment: Welcome, if it helped you, could you pls mark it answer ?